# What is the correct syntax to point at multiple elements in a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<body>

<p class="initial">Number One!</p>
<p class="initial">Number Two!</p>
<p class="initial">Number Three!</p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("initial");
x[0].innerHTML = "<span class=\"fix\">super duper</span>";
</script>

</body>
```

`x[0].innerHTML` points to the first element.  However what if I wanted to change the innerHTML of several elements in the array?  For instance the first and the third.  `x[0, 2].innerHTML` doesn't work. I've been looking for the syntax online and I can't find anything.

Comment: You can't do it that way. You need a statement for each individually.

Comment: Don't forget to read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) when you're happy with an answer. You can only accept one but you're able to upvote any answer that you think is useful to say 'thanks'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to run the code multiple times:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    x[i].innerHTML = "<span class=\"fix\">super duper</span>";
}
```

If there are particular elements you want, create an array and iterate through with a [`forEach` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
var desiredElems = [1, 3, 7, 9];
desiredElems.forEach(function(element) {
    x[element].innerHTML = "<span class=\"fix\">super duper</span>";
});
```

Comment: Thanks Aurora!  That's a good way to solve that one.  But what if I didn't want to fix every instance?  Like if there were 99 and I wanted to fix 5 scattered randomly throughout the page.  There isn't shorthand for that?

Comment: @DR01D just added that for you.

Answer (score 3):

Assignments are **expressions that return the assigned value**, so you can do the following:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("initial");
x[0].innerHTML = x[2].innerHTML = "<span class=\"fix\">super duper</span>";
```

```html
<p class="initial">Number One!</p>
<p class="initial">Number Two!</p>
<p class="initial">Number Three!</p>
```

---

**If you want to change more than a handful indices**, you could define the indices as an array and use a loop:

```js
var indices = [0, 2];

var x = document.getElementsByClassName("initial");
indices.forEach(function(i) {
  x[i].innerHTML = "<span class=\"fix\">super duper</span>";
})
```

```html
<p class="initial">Number One!</p>
<p class="initial">Number Two!</p>
<p class="initial">Number Three!</p>
```

Comment: Ok awesome that works!  But what if there were 99 instances of "initial" and I wanted to work on # 3, 17, 35, 36, 89, 91.  I would list east one individually?  There isn't shorthand?  Thanks Timo!

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate an array with `for...of`:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("initial");
for (var i of [0,2])
  x[i].innerHTML = "<span class=\"fix\">super duper</span>";
```

```html
<p class="initial">Number One!</p>
<p class="initial">Number Two!</p>
<p class="initial">Number Three!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Oriol, I think that is it!  That's gold!

Comment: Note that `for...of` is an ES6 feature and possibly [not supported by all targeted browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility), e.g. any version of Internet Explorer before IE12 (Edge).